# Comparing 2 CSV file,In which last line to be skipped in comparing.Any better way to do it?

Tags: python, csv

I Have 2 csv files.I am using csv dict reader

```
csv1.csv
abc,def,ghi
abc1,def1,ghi1
abc2,def2,ghi2

csv2.csv
abc4,def4,ghi4
abc5,def5,ghi5
abc2,def2,ghi2
```

In which csv2 file is compared with csv1.csv.
**I have to compare two csv1 files by ignoring the last row of csv2.**
Any ways in csv dict reader to ignore the last row?
or Can I Skip the row if the column value matches particular value?

Comment: What to do you mean by compare the files?

Comment: To find the row difference

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I still don't really understand what you mean by comparing rows and row difference.

Regardless, you could use something like the following to read all but the last row of the second csv file:

```
import csv

def csv_reader_ignore_last_row(csv_filename):
    with open(csv_filename,'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        lastrow = reader.next()
        for row in reader:
            yield lastrow
            lastrow = row

for row in csv_reader_ignore_last_row(filename):
    print ', '.join(row)
```

You can skip a row of a `csv.reader` object by calling `reader.next()` or `next(reader)` at any time.

Comment: Python_Dude: If you add an example of comparing a row from each file, I can be more specific in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be know number of lines in `csv2` first, and then use `itertools.islice` to slice out the last line.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> import csv
with open('csv2.csv') as f:
    line_count = sum(1 for _ in f)  #get the line count
    f.seek(0)                       #move the file pointer to the start of the file
    f = islice(f, 0, line_count-1)  #skip last line
    reader = csv.reader(f)         
    print list(reader)
...     
[['abc4', 'def4', 'ghi4'], ['abc5', 'def5', 'ghi5']]
```